# How to fix "error: expected primary -expression before ')' token" in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure

I am writing this code, and I have 2 structures and 1 function. The function takes in one of the structures as reference and uses the variables in it. The problem is that I keep getting the following 2 errors:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
error: 'arrayDrink' was not declared in this scope
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I tried the other structure too, but I keep getting this error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
const unsigned int maxDrinkItems = 20;

struct DrinkItem
{
    unsigned int id;
    string name;
    double price;
    unsigned int NumDrinksOfSameType;
    unsigned int drinksPurchased = 0;

};

struct DrinkMachine
{
    unsigned int versionNumber = 1;
    unsigned int totalDrinks;
    unsigned int arrayDrink[maxDrinkItems];
};

bool create(DrinkMachine &drinkMachine)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("drink_machine.txt");

    if(inputFile.fail())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {

        while (inputFile.eof() || drinkMachine.totalDrinks == 20)
        {
            inputFile >> drinkMachine.totalDrinks;

            for (int i = 0; i < drinkMachine.totalDrinks; i++)
            {
                inputFile >> arrayDrink[i].name;
                inputFile >> arrayDrink[i].price;
                inputFile >> arrayDrink[i].NumDrinksOfSameType;
            }

        }

        inputFile.close();
        return true;
    }

}
```

here I call the function:

```
int main()
{
    create(DrinkMachine);

    return 0;
}
```

I want it to take in data from the file and put it into the array of structures, but I keep getting errors.

Comment: `arrayDrink` is undefined and `while(!eof())` is almost always wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition in the while loop doesn't work the way you think.

```
while (inputFile.eof() || drinkMachine.totalDrinks == 20)
```

When doing input extraction in a loop you should *first* do the extraction, check if it succeeds, then continue. `eof()` checks if the eofbit (end-of-stream bit) in the stream is set, which occurs when the previous extraction failed. Typically when doing extraction you check stream validity with `fail()`.

```
while (inputFile >> drinkMachine.totalDrinks && !inputFile.fail() && drinkMachine.totalDrinks == 20)
```

We can get rid of `!inputFile.fail()` since every stream has a built in `operator bool()` so it checks `fail()` implicitly:

```
while (inputFile >> drinkMachine.totalDrinks && drinkMachine.totalDrinks == 20)
```

Your other issues are pointed out by Acorn.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your code.

First, you need to access your `drinkMachine` object to get to `arrayDrink` here:

```
{
    inputFile >> arrayDrink[i].name;
    inputFile >> arrayDrink[i].price;
    inputFile >> arrayDrink[i].NumDrinksOfSameType;
}
```

See what you do in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < drinkMachine.totalDrinks; i++)
```

---

Another one: you are trying to call `create` with a type, rather than an object:

```
create(DrinkMachine);
```

Instead, you need to define a `DrinkMachine` object and then pass it to `create`.

Comment: how do I get the object to go there?

Comment: How do i define and create the object?

Comment: Like when you do `int i = 0;`. If defining objects is confusing for you, I suggest you take some time to read a tutorial or a good book!